# On Yii framework, getting "Unable to resolve the request'

Tags: yii, controller

I'm trying to modify a previous developer's app and I believe I'm mimicking previous controllers but keep getting this error.  After reading up, it appears my code is correct, but obviously not.  Here is my code for the file .../public_html/protected/controllers/ProcessRawDataController.php

```
<?php
class ProcessRawData extends Controller {
   public function actionIndex()
   {
      echo 'bla';
      exit;
   }
}
?>
```

When I go to this URL: mydomain.com/index.php?r=processRawData/index or mydomain.com/index.php?r=processRawData i get the error.  I've tried changing to all lower case as well with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I just realized the error.  The class declaration is missing the word "Controller".  It should read

`class ProcessRawDataController extends Controller {`